# asp.net mvc View strange thing @:

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am fairly new to MVC `@: User:  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Username)   <br/>` and I saw the "@:" written in the view... What is it used for?

Comment: It denotes the Razor view engine

Comment: @jmoerdyk yea but "User" is just plain text in my situation so....?

Comment: [ASP.NET MVC 3: Razor’s @: and <text> syntax](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax)